# phpseclib, using double slashes

Tags: php, windows, ssh, phpseclib

OK so I have this line,

```
$ssh->exec('cd E:\\Titan\ Torque\\Jobs');
```

Now how to I use this with the double slashes? I mean I need 2 slashes to be sent not one the command:

```
cd E:\\Titan\ Torque\\Jobs
```

Is what I need to be executed.

P.S. The ssh server is running on windows, this command runs fine in putty but PHP is stripping it down to:

```
cd E:\Titan\ Torque\Jobs
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you escape the backslashes with backslashes, they should work.

```
$ssh->exec('cd E:\\\\Titan\\ Torque\\\\Jobs');
```

In a test:

```
echo 'E\\:a thing with\slashes\\';
echo "\n";
echo 'E\\\\:a thing with\\\\slashes\\';
```

gives

```
E\:a thing with\slashes\ 
E\\:a thing with\\slashes\
```

In case you're curious, the reason a single backslash works at all, is because `\` isn't a special escape sequence so it's put into the resultant string literally.

Comment: Many thanks, is there a way to do this automatically? just so I wont need to edit every command being used.

Comment: I don't know of a way to change the PHP used to parse the strings, nor to change the way Exec works, but you should be able to do a search-replace in your document I guess.

Comment: No worries could always do something like a replace on double quotes to be 4 as there will be times I need just 1 slash for spaces.